# Preventing Menu from exceeding screen size

Tags: java, swing

I've got a very large list of Menu-Items added to a Menu element, leading to the menu growing to a size bigger than even the screen height.
Besides splitting the items into more sub-menues, I have been unable to find any solution to prevent this from happening, since neither the Layout-Manager nor the maximum size of the Menu-Element seem to adress this.

I would prefer a kind of multi-column menu or scrollable menu instead, but as far as I can tell there is no implementation of either kind. I'm open to any ideas on how to archieve this.

Comment: Have a (single) menu item to pop up an option pane or dialog containing a list in a scroll pane. Note that extremely long menus are difficult for most users.

Comment: I agree, that long menues are far from optimal. In this case it's a list of user-supplied tags, so the number of items grows a lot naturally.
Popping up a new Pane for selection may be a clean solution, thanks for the idea.

Comment: From a user point of view I only can agree with Andrew from the bottom of my heart. I really _hate_ large menus as they are hard to scan through, often hard to navigate and also hard to memorize. Many applications thus now do the following: they provide simpler menus that just contain the most used commands (ideally customizable) as well as some dialog that contains a scrollable tree or list along with a "filter" text field that let's the user search for a menu entry by "name contains X".